# Translate Breadcrumps from Rank Math in Wordpress

Tags: plugins, translation

I have a website on Wordpress in Bulgarian. I added bread crumps from Rank Math and everything is fine, but the bread crumps on pagination. See, everything is in Bulgarian but the last part which is the page (2,3,4, etc) and its URL
[image]

The language of the website is set to Bulgarian and I pretty much did whatever I could think of but nothing worked. I'll be very grateful if somebody helps. Thank you!